# Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties Error in a Regex class

Tags: regex, swift, swift2, initialization, nsregularexpression

I get this error message that says "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties"

```
class Regex {
let internalExpression: NSRegularExpression
let pattern: String

init(_ pattern: String) {
    self.pattern = pattern
    var error: NSError?

    do {
        self.internalExpression = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}//Error Message Goes Here

func test(input: String) -> Bool {
    let matches = self.internalExpression.matchesInString(input, options: [], range:NSMakeRange(0, input.characters.count))
    return matches.count > 0
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the pattern is invalid then `NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, ...)`
fails and throws an error, so that `self.internalExpression` is not
initialized. You cannot create an object without initializing all its
properties.

So you have to decide how to handle that situation. One option would
be to make the initializer *failable:*

```
init?(_ pattern: String) {
    self.pattern = pattern
    do {
        self.internalExpression = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Then the caller has to check if the initialization was successful:

```
if let regex = Regex("...") {
    // ...
} else {
    print("could not create Regex")
}
```

You can also make the initializer `throw`ing and forward the error:

```
init(_ pattern: String) throws {
    self.pattern = pattern
    self.internalExpression = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive)
}
```

Then the caller has to catch the error:

```
do {
    let regex = try Regex("...")
    // ...
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("could not create regex:", error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Finally, if an invalid pattern is considered as a *programming error*
in your program, then abort the execution for an invalid pattern:

```
init(_ pattern: String) {
    self.pattern = pattern
    do {
        self.internalExpression = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        fatalError("could not create regex: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```